# undo apt-get update (in docker container)

Tags: docker, apt-get

i'm working with docker and want to create a minimal new layer by installing an application in a zip-file on top of an ubuntu image. The ubuntu image has neither wget nor unzip installed, so i install those by using apt-get which requires an `apt-get update` first

```
docker run -it --name app_container ubuntu:latest
# now i have terminal access to the fresh app_container

# install wget and unzip
apt-get update
apt-get install wget -y
apt-get install unzip -y

# download and unpack the app
# ...

# remove wget and unzip
apt-get purge unzip
apt-get purge wget
# i need to remove some dependencies of wget that are no longer needed
apt-get autoremove
```

at this point it would be nice if the only content of the new docker layer would be the new application, but there are still the files created/updated by `apt-get update`. I tried to remove those by using

```
apt-get clean
```

but a

```
docker diff app_container
```

revealed that there where lots of changed files left (that didn't belong to the app). Ok, so those are negligible in size (mainly some residual wget certificates in `/etc/ssl` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info` and 23MB of archive files in `/var/lib/app/lists`) but in the spirit of the cleanest possible docker layer: Is there a smart way to remove those, too? ('smart' meaning without resorting to brute-force rm)

Comment: Related: [Minimizing Docker Images with apt-get build deps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28967591/418413)

Comment: try to install with `apt-get install --no-install-recommends`

Comment: - the minimizing docker images link results in removing everything from /var/lib/app/lists which seems to be the as-good-as-it-gets.

Comment: @user2915097 's idea to use `--no-install-recommends` installs wget without certificate validation, so we have to use wget with the `--no-check-certificate` option. It's doable but not really worth it, `--no-install-recommends` seems to modify equally many files as my initial version using `apt get autoremove` to remove wget's dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Use of apt-get update should be paired with `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` in the same layer.

Use this online tool to get some optimization and clarity check:
https://www.fromlatest.io/

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be no better suggestion than to remove everything from `/var/lib/app/lists`